# Over confident vs Overly confident

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

What is the difference between over and overly? what these words called like one adverb or another noun etc. My English is not all good.

If I am saying over confident and overly confident, what is the difference?

Comment: There is very little difference, aside from style. Note that [**overconfident**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overconfident) is actually a single closed-word adjective. It would nornally not be written as *over confident* in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

To my ear:
He was over-confident (in his ability to recall information), so didn't bother studying.
He didn't bother studying, overly-confident (in his ability to recall information).

The former is an adjective phrase and the latter an adverb(ial) phrase.